# Couldn't parse csv file if value contains from '

Tags: yandex, clickhouse

Here is demo DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE X (
    eventdate        Date default toDate(now()),
    f1               String,
    f2               String,
    f3               String
) ENGINE = MergeTree(eventdate, (f1, f2, f3), 8192)
```

When I try to import data, clickhous fails with error:

```
$echo "US,'Ewa Beach, Test" | clickhouse-client --database default --query "insert into X(f1, f2, f3) format CSV"

Code: 27. DB::Exception: Cannot parse input: expected , at end of
stream.: (at row 1)
```

Here is my click house version(it time of writing it's latest version, if I am not mistaking):

```
$ clickhouse-client --version
ClickHouse client version 1.1.54385.
```

The problem is **'** symbol in the value of field *f2*.
**Please, any workaround to make it works?**

Maybe is there some option to force using a only double quote as a string delimiter, and consider single quote as plain symbol without special meaning? Please, any solution is welcome.

I just tested with same values but as tsv, and it works. But unfortunately I cannot migrate to tsv right now. I need to find out some workaround for csv to make it work with signle quote in field value.

P.S.

Interesting that if left only two fields, it parses csv correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE X (
    eventdate        Date default toDate(now()),
    f1               String,
    f2               String
) ENGINE = MergeTree(eventdate, (f1, f2), 8192)
```

The following query workds:

```
$echo "US,'Ewa Beach" | clickhouse-client --database default --query "insert into X(f1, f2) format CSV"
```

Here is related [issue](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/2517) on the GitHub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. I've created a PR https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/pull/2574

With that you can specify `format_allow_csv_single_quote=0` to parse csv data with string field starting with a `'`

Edit:

Now it's merged.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes for values like this.

```
echo "US,\"'Ewa Beach\", Test" | clickhouse-client --host ch_srv --query "insert into X(f1, f2, f3) format CSV"
```

This works.

```
:) select * from X format CSV;
SELECT *
FROM X 
FORMAT CSV
"2018-06-28","US","'Ewa Beach","Test"
:) select * from X;
SELECT *
FROM X 
┌──eventdate─┬─f1─┬─f2──────────┬─f3───┐
│ 2018-06-28 │ US │ \'Ewa Beach │ Test │
└────────────┴────┴─────────────┴──────┘
```